# Missing properties of _spPageContextInfo after page load

Tags: javascript, spcontext, csom, jsom

I have a script that provision site collections under a specific managed path. In these site collections, I have sub webs with page libraries in which I have several different pages with custom javascript code that requires some properties that can be accessed through the `_spPageContextInfo` object.

I have two functions that both need to get the current `pageItemId` and it's corresponding `pageListId`. My problem is that after the page has loaded, none of these two properties are available through the `_spPageContextInfo` object.

The strange thing is that I can access them if I pause the loading of the page during page load through a javascript breakpoint on `$(document).ready()`, and at that point both properties are available.

Another thing I noticed is that when I've paused the execution, the `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` is set to `"/myManaged/Path/mySubweb"` while when the page is loaded, it is set to `"/"`. The same applies to `webServerRelativeUrl`,`webAbsoluteUrl` and `siteAbsoluteUrl`, though they revert back to the root instead of the current site collection and web.

How come that the properties of `_spPageContextInfo` changes from these two states, and why aren't `pageItemId` and `pageListId` available when the page has finished loading? Does this have something to do with the fact that they are created under a managed path?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the answer was right in front of me all the time. When the execution of the script paused on the breakpoint, the `_spPageContextInfo` was correct, as stated in the question. Stepping forward in the code, I tried to spot at what moment the properties of the object changed, and it all became quite obvious.

One of the functions looked something like this

`$('#element').load("https://pathToAnotherSite"), function() {
...
}`

When the above code got executed, the current `_spPageContextInfo`changed to the context of the above site path instead of the current one. I'm not sure if it is possible and if so how you can change the current `_spPageContextInfo` (I tried making a dummy `$.load()` to my current page path) so my solution is to save away the `_spPageContextInfo` in another variable while it's accessible.

Comments or solutions on how to switch context would be very nice.

Comment: I think _spPageContextInfo is rendered in the HTML (a script tag) by SharePoint, so when you do a .load, and get an new page. It will overwrite the current _spPageContextInfo variable

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I changed my solution and reassigned the `_spPageContextInfo` after the load, because I noticed that some OOB features stopped working, since they most likely relies on it to be linked to the current page.